# first time implementing module pattern variable is undefined

Tags: javascript, module-pattern

here is my code

```
    var s;
var AddEvent =  {
    settings : {
        saveButton : $('#uploadfiles1'),
        cancelSpeech :  $('.cancelSpeech'),
        datePicker : $(".datepicker"),
        eventName : $('input[name=eventname]'),
        eventDate : $('input[name=eventdate]')
    },
    init:function(s){
        s = this.settings;
        this.BindEvents();
        $('.Wallpapers').addClass('active');
        $('input, textarea').placeholder();
    },
    BindEvents:function(){
        this.CancelButton();
        this.DatePicker();
       // this.SaveButton();
        $('input[type=text],textarea').on('keyup change',function(){
            AddEvent.FieldsCheck(); 
        });
    },
    CancelButton: function()
    {
        s.cancelSpeech.on('click',function(){
            var referrer =  document.referrer;
            window.location = referrer;
        });
    },
    DatePicker :function()
    {
        s.datePicker.datepicker({
            //defaultDate: +7,
            showOtherMonths: true,
            autoSize: true,
            //appendText: '(dd-mm-yyyy)',
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
        });
    },
    SaveButton: function()
    {
        this.ClearFields();
    },
    FieldsCheck: function()
    {
        alert(s.eventName.attr('name'));
        if(s.eventName.val()!='' && s.eventDate.val() !='' && $('textarea').val()!='')
        {
            s.saveButton.removeAttr('disabled').removeClass('disabled');
        }
        else
            s.saveButton.attr('disabled','disabled').addClass('disabled');
    },
    ClearFields:function()
    {
        $('input,textarea').val('');
        this.FieldsCheck();
    }
};
$(function(){
    AddEvent.init(s);
});
```

i am impletenting this example http://css-tricks.com/how-do-you-structure-javascript-the-module-pattern-edition/

but each time when i type in my input field at this line i get undefined in alert

```
alert(s.eventName.attr('name'));
```

please tell me what am i doing wrong i tried to search but couldnt find anything usefull.

edit: here i created a little [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lp6rE/9/) i am getting

```
TypeError: this.settings is undefined
[Break On This Error]   

console.log(this.settings.eventName.attr('id'));
```

thanks

Comment: Why aere you using `s` at all? You already have `this.settings` in the scope. If you want to shorten it for typing, define it as a local variable *inside*  the function, not globally.

Comment: this.settings also give me undefined error :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here :

```
var s;
AddEvent.init(s);
```

There is no way after this to have `s` defined.

A solution would be to simply not pass `s` (and no declare it in the arguments of the function) :

```
init:function(s){
    s = this.settings;
...
AddEvent.init();
```

But that lets a variable polluting the global namespace.

If you want your `settings` to be accessed from all your functions, you could embed in in a closure :

```
var AddEvent =  (function(){
    var settings;
    return {
        init:function(){
                settings = {
                        saveButton : $('#uploadfiles1'),
                        cancelSpeech :  $('.cancelSpeech'),
                        datePicker : $(".datepicker"),
                        eventName : $('input[name=eventname]'),
                        eventDate : $('input[name=eventdate]')
                };
            this.BindEvents();
            $('.Wallpapers').addClass('active');
            $('input, textarea').placeholder();
        },
        BindEvents:function(){
            this.CancelButton();
            this.DatePicker();
           // this.SaveButton();
            $('input[type=text],textarea').on('keyup change',function(){
                AddEvent.FieldsCheck(); 
            });
        },
        CancelButton: function()
        {
            settings.cancelSpeech.on('click',function(){
                var referrer =  document.referrer;
                window.location = referrer;
            });
        },
        DatePicker :function()
        {
            settings.datePicker.datepicker({
                //defaultDate: +7,
                showOtherMonths: true,
                autoSize: true,
                //appendText: '(dd-mm-yyyy)',
                dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
            });
        },
        SaveButton: function()
        {
            this.ClearFields();
        },
        FieldsCheck: function()
        {
            alert(settings.eventName.attr('name'));
            if(settings.eventName.val()!='' && settings.eventDate.val() !='' && $('textarea').val()!='')
            {
                settings.saveButton.removeAttr('disabled').removeClass('disabled');
            }
            else
                settings.saveButton.attr('disabled','disabled').addClass('disabled');
        },
        ClearFields:function()
        {
            $('input,textarea').val('');
            this.FieldsCheck();
        }
    }
})();

$(function(){
    AddEvent.init();
});
```

Comment: now when i page load i see an error 



TypeError: s is undefined
[Break On This Error]  

s.cancelSpeech.on('click',function(){

Comment: i tried this pattern as well this also give me undefined on the alert,but now i copied all the code that you posted and still getting the undefined error on alert.

Comment: @NajeebK maybe `input[name=eventname]` doesn’t exist? This script uses DOM references, are you sure you are calling it on domReady? There are many things that can cause the `undefined` alert, not just the pattern.

Comment: In fact the init should entirely be in the init function, if this code is called before the DOM is ready. I edit.

Comment: please check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Lp6rE/9/ i created ,please click on the input field and check your console , i am getting this.setting is undefined as message

Comment: the edited code works but what was wrong the the module pattern?

Comment: The first problem was that s in the init function was a local variable, lost at the end of the function execution. Another problem was that settings was initialized before the dom was ready (and so the jquery collections could be empty).

Comment: thanks for the help , but i am really curious about the module pattern , is there no way of implementing that? because that seems really simple like this example http://css-tricks.com/how-do-you-structure-javascript-the-module-pattern-edition/

Comment: There are many solutions. The IIFE module pattern (the one I used) is the cleanest one in my opinion. I gives more details about it in [this related answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15781187/does-javascript-have-a-concept-like-apis/15781217#15781217).